# Eclipse WindowBuilder uses different LookAndFeel than it puts into the main method

Tags: java, eclipse, look-and-feel, windowbuilder

So I created a GUI for my program with the WindowBuilder from the Eclipse Marketplace. After I finished designing, i implemented it into my program but on the first start, I noticed how ugly the buttons and slider looked and changed the LookAndFeel variable.

I did some research and got suggested to tick the box in the Eclipse settings for the WindowBuilder implementing the choosen LookAndFeel as displayed in the built in preview. I did so and it sure worked, but for some reason whilst getting this in the preview:

[image: Preview Image in WindowBuilder]

I get this when running my program:

[image: Screenshot of the program running]

I have no idea why this is happening, so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Oh, the reasons not to use a "window builder" - check out [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).  You probably want to set the "system" look and feel on startup

Comment: @howlger Oh no, I've not spent years of my life undoing the mess that "window builders" create, no, I haven't , so no, I wouldn't have any idea of how "special" they are, especially when they aren't usable between different IDEs ... that's a whole other problem 

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, "they aren't usable between different IDEs" does not apply to WindowBuilder. That's the special thing of WindowBuilder.

Comment: @howlger In my "experience", they create "lazy" habits and difficult to maintain code - sorry, you're not going to sell me on it - I gave up on "form editors" along time ago

Comment: Where is a real problem here? Both screenshots show the same layout with a slightly different theme. WindowBuilder is about layout, not about theming. Maybe just your expectations of what WindowBuilder does are wrong.

Comment: @howlger My "experience" is based on a lot of "form editors", they all tend to suffer from the same problems, because they don't encourage decent habits

Comment: @MadProgrammer You wouldn't say that if you knew WindowBuilder. Again, WindowBuilder is conceptually different from " lot of form editors".

Comment: @howlger It still suffers from the same problems that developers without a deep understanding of how to use the underlying APIs and layers still make - stuff everything into a single, top level container, because they can't be bothered to actually sit back and think about how the structure needs to work together, how the non-ui parts of the code need to interact with the UI parts, how different state effects different aspects of the UI differently - sorry, not a fan of "form builders" in general - I've undone enough of them (including window builder code)

Comment: @howlger I've built UIs with Visual basic, Visual Studio (C/C++/C#), iOS, Android, Web and Java - all the visual editors suck at scale - I'm not bashing "WindowBuilder", I'm bashing form editors in general. Spending the time to learn how to make UIs by hand is generally a better place to start, and builds better long term skills

Comment: @MadProgrammer Everything you say is based on the wrong generalization from your experiences with other GUI builders. You are not the first one not knowing WindowBuilder making such comments on questions about WindowBuilder.

Comment: @howlger No, it's not. I respect that you don't agree, but that doesn't make me wrong - form editors promote bad habits.  But "Window Builder is different" - no, it's not and I have undone its work as well.  I will always encourage developers to make the time and effort to learn the underlying APIs and understand how they should be worked with first, it will make them better developers in the long run.

Comment: @howlger And when ever some has an issue with building there UIs by hand, there's always that someone who says "uSe A fOrM bUiLdEr", don't be that guy  (and please, don't assume I've not had experience with Window Builder )

Comment: @howlger First, my comment about "usable between IDEs" is a generalisation about "form editors".  The problem the OP is having isn't about "Window Builder", it's about not understanding how the Swing API works, which is been "covered up" by the use of a "form editor".  I "recommend" making the time to learn the underlying API and it's workflows and supporting frameworks. We spend way to much time "undoing" form editor work on this site

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't know "Window Builder". Maybe you are confusing "Window Builder" with "WindowBuilder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, problem was simple in the end: Because all the components were static and not object owned, the style was different. So if anyone ever encounters this problem: Make the variables for JTextArea, JTextField etc. not static!